# Controller reading component data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-components, angularjs-forms

My idea is to create a big form from separated components. So this is my main template:

```
<form novalidate>
    <div class="row">
        <user></user>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submit()"> Submit   </button>
</form>
```

and its controller (the template is binded from ui route config to the controller)

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
        .controller('formCtrl', formCtrl);

    function formCtrl ($scope) {
        $scope.submit = function() {
            console.log("read data");
        }
    }      
})();
```

Now, the user component:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var module = angular.module('app.user');

    module.component("user", {
        templateUrl: "app/user/user.html",
        controllerAs: "model",
        controller: function () {
            var model = this;
            model.user = {};            
        }
    });
})();
```

and the user template:

```
<form novalidate>
    <form-group>
        <label for="inputUser"> Name <label>
        <input ng-model="model.user.name" id="inputUser" type="text" placeholder="User"/>
    </form-group>
    <form-group>
        <label for="inputUser"> Email <label>
        <input ng-model="model.user.email" id="inputUser" type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
    </form-group>
    <div>
        {{model.user | json}}
    </div>
</form>
```

Now I want to be able to read user data when the user do the submit. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using components, depending on the type of component (smart or dumb), you have to emit an output to the parent controller to handle such thing. But in this case, you can use `ngModel` to handle a model and change it on the parent from within the component. For example:

Working snippet:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.submit = function() {
      console.log($scope.user);
    }
  })
  .component("user", {
    bindings: {
      user: '=ngModel'
    },
    templateUrl: "app/user/user.html",
    controllerAs: "model",
    controller: function() {}
  });

angular.element(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<form novalidate ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <user ng-model="user"></user>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="app/user/user.html">
  <form novalidate>
    <div>
      <label for="inputUser">Name
        <label>
          <input ng-model="model.user.name" id="inputUser" type="text" placeholder="User" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="inputUser">Email
        <label>
          <input ng-model="model.user.email" id="inputUser" type="email" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
    <div>
      {{ model.user | json }}
    </div>
  </form>
</script>
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Do you know any useful resource to deep into it?

Comment: @FacundoGFlores actually it's a pretty shallow concept, there is no much for deeping into, it's basically about `bindings`, but I've seen this issue being discused with component directives instead of components directly, but the ideas are very similar (e.g., https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2969-passing-ngmodelcontroller-into-a-component-directive-controller-in-angularjs.htm)

Comment: Yes, I saw it with directives, I thought components would have a particular angular-component way but it does not. And yes, it is all about bindings. Thank you for helping me

Comment: @FacundoGFlores The most deep I can imagine is having access `ngModelController` to handle form validations and stuff like that, anyway, cheers :{D

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be `$$childTail`. So if I want to access to user:

```
$scope.$$childTail.model.user
```